# Keeping hover state active between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

So I have two elements on top of one another.

'#a': which currently has visibility:hidden applied.
'#b': which is visible.

I want to be able to hover over #b to show #a, then be able to mouseover #a and have it stay visible even though I'm no longer over #b. This is so #a can be interacted with.

If mousing out of the area of #a and #b it should disappear. I've tried applying the same class to both '.hover' and using the following to no avail.

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){$('#a').css('visibility','visible');},function(){$('#a').css('visibility','hidden');});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are both within the same container, just apply your `:hover` pseudo class to the parent element and apply the styles using that.

**HTML**

```
<a class="hoverable">
    <div id="a">Foo</div>
    <dvi id="b">Bar</div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.hoverable:hover #a, .hoverable:hover #b {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Should bear something similar. If however the items are not in a common parent this won't work for you. Please post your code so we can get a better understanding :)

**AN ALTERNATE CONCEPT**

If both elements are direct siblings you can also try something along the lines of

```
#b:hover + #a {
    visibility:visible
}
```

This would require b to be drawn before a however. you could manipulate this ordering using other css.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are not connected you can try mouseenter on b and mouseleave on a

[Fiddle for mosue enter on one and mouseleave on another](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku42N/)

```
 $("#b").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#a").show();
 });
 $("#a").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#a").hide();
 });
```